Looking For a Solution to manage Repeating Tasks for Users in Flask Web App
Context:
I'm running a Flask-based SaaS web app (server A), featuring a page where users can send request to an endpoint on server by clicking "START", the endpoint on server will  fetch data from external APIs. The JS on the page will send request to the endpoint repeatedly every 3 seconds.They can also halt this process by clicking "STOP".
Requirements:
I need a solution that allows the server to continuously fetch data from external APIs for users without requiring them to keep the browser or app open until they decide to stop the process manually or the server initiates the stop.
Current Solutions and Challenges:
Sequential User Loop: Initially, I implemented a loop through all active users who clicked "START" to send requests to external APIs. However, this method faces the challenge of users' requests not being synchronized. Each request takes approximately 3 seconds to process. Consequently, users who initiate the process later have to wait for the previous requests to finish. For instance, if there are 100 users, the 100th user would need to wait at least 300 seconds before their task begins processing.
Celery-Beat/Redis Approach: To mitigate the synchronization issue, I created an endpoint on server A, with the user's ID as a parameter. Additionally, I set up a Celery-Beat/Redis application on another server (server B) with four cores. Whenever a user presses "START", a new task is created on server B, scheduled to call the endpoint on server A with the user's ID at a 3-second interval. While this solution has been functional, it faces scalability challenges. The Celery/Beat application on server B seems to capably handle only around 10 concurrent tasks. Beyond this threshold, new tasks experience significant delays, sometimes up to 10 minutes. Furthermore, attempting to halt these tasks doesn't immediately stop them, but rather waits for all scheduled tasks to complete. This has led to a situation where I've had to deploy multiple servers (currently 10) solely to run the Celery/Beat application.
Seeking a Robust Solution:
I'm searching for a solution that effectively addresses these challenges, ensuring that all requests to external APIs are sent without being contingent on the completion of previous requests. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

the task is cpu bound or IO bound?. Can each task's data parameter and output be the same when api param unchanged?
